# Symfony 2 on shared hosting?

Tags: symfony, deployment, hosting, shared

I'm developing my app in Symfony 2, and one of the things that i have kept in mind is that symfony 2 have a lot of requirements. I know that in my pc works. But i've never tryed to deploy my app in a shared hosting. Is not that i want all the functionalities of the framework, i only need that the app works, and also the caching works.

1. Do i need a special shared hosting or it can run in any hosting that have (of course) PHP and the Database Engine that i'm using?
2. If i do, which shared hosting may I use?
3. If i don't, do i need a special configuration?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also want to be cautious for shared hosting servers that use separate php versions for CLI vs Apache. If this is the case, even though you can run parts of your application via ssh, you may not be able to run most of your Symfony2 application via http.

I think you may be better off investing in a cheap VPS for Symfony2 development as it allows more flexibility and will ultimately save you more time. A lot of vps these days are almost as cheap as shared hosting anyway.

Comment: Thanks!, i was looking for a VPS that can be scallable. I will work directly to the server while developing the app. So at first something very basic will do. (I saw a 5 bucks VPS with 256 ram, 20gb of HDD and so), do you think this will be enough?

Comment: Yes I think it's plenty. I've got about 6 applications on one VPS hosting plan right now and I've only used about 13gb space so far with no issues with 1gb ram. Cool thing about vps is you can upgrade your existing plan very easily.

Answer (score 4):

These are the requirements for running symfony2

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/requirements.html

Have a look at it and compare with your hosting provider and see if they matches.
Most of them should match othwise give the support team a call and they will look at it.

usually most of the Hosting companies have symfony2 available as addon so i think they might have all requirements but ask you can confirm with them. like Godaddy

Comment: Thanks!, i will check GoDaddy.

Answer (score -2):

Well No doubt Symfony requires lot of pre requsites. specially when it comes to shared hosting. I practice my self managed cloud hosing services of Cloudways. This is so because they provide popular php framework as one click app installation, Moreover, i found installation process of symfony on cloud server over there blog. Just followed the simple steps and symfony 3 was installed on my server.